# How to update a frame with a scrollbar linked in it that has buttons so that it updates and works correctly when adding buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm writing an application in tkinter which has the following structure:

1. Notebook
2. Tab (frame on the notebook)
3. Canvas (on the frame)
4. SecondFrame (on the canvas) ← this is where I want to pack my buttons
5. MyButtons (on second frame)

While scrollbar is linked as expected to my canvas.

Lets say I have 20 buttons when running the program and by pressing any of them I want to destroy the last button

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.title('Update Scrollbar')

notebook = Notebook(root)
tab1 = Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(tab1, text='Home')
notebook.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

canvas = Canvas(tab1)
second_frame = Frame(canvas)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(tab1, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor='center')

scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

canvas.pack()

# With this function I destroy the last button:

def delete_buttons():
    list(second_frame.winfo_children())[-1].destroy()
    second_frame.update_idletasks()

# Here I pack my buttons all with a command 'delete_buttons'

for i in range(20):
    Button(second_frame, text='Button' + str(i), command=delete_buttons).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However when clicking on a button, the last button is destroyed but an ugly space is created in the top and bottom of the window. (Because of a missing button that took space before I suppose.)

[image: before pressing any button]
[image: after pressing any button]

Comment: I dont know why your code is acting like that but if we don't know where the vault occured in this code we are adding new code to fix this as a developer.So I recommend that adding new for loop after the scroll update to specify each button has default position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is appearing because of the `anchor=` option you're using to create the `Canvas` window object:

```
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor='center')
```

Which causes the contents to be re-centered every time one of the `Button`s is deleted.

To prevent some of the extra space resulting from the deletion from getting distributed to the top of the `Canvas`, simply anchor the window object to its NorthWest (upper left) corner like this:

```
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor='nw')
```

Also note that `second_frame.update_idletasks()` call in the `delete_buttons()` function isn't necessary.